# i have tried this code many times. But it always force closes. Can anyone find out the error in the code

Tags: android

this code is for getting details from a php server by posting two data num,db and getting a response.
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Button b;
TextView num;
TextView dob;
String db;
String x;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    num=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    dob=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    x=(String) num.getText();
    db=(String) dob.getText();

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            submit();
        }
    });

}
```

submit fn is for posting two values num,db into the server to get a response.

```
public String submit(){
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registerno", x ));  
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", db ));            

    String response = "";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.pnrinbox.com/premfin.php");

    try 
    {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                response += s;
            }

            Log.d( "After call, response: " , " " + response);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    return response;
}
```

posting two data items into a php server and getting data back.

Comment: How about you read your logcat and see what's broken? Or post it here if you don't understand it. Most likely, it's a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Google that to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill bet you are getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException. All networking operations must be done on a non-UI thread. I would recommend looking up the AsyncTask class in the android documentaion: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

You will probably find that you need to move the body of your `submit()` function into the `doInBackground()` function of an asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use AsyncTask for network access, and then call the AsyncTask from the UI thread to return the desired value. Also, you'll have to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` after the `</application>` in the manifest.xml file.